# Ensure temporary tables are always deleted within stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I have an ASP.NET MVC app published in IIS Server which calls an SP:

```
BEGIN

if OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#MyTempTable') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  DROP TABLE #MyTempTable
END

CREATE TABLE #MyTempTable
(
   someField int,
   someFieldMore nvarchar(50)
)

... Use of temp table here
... And then drop table again at the end..

DROP TABLE #MyTempTable

END
```

This app is being used by a lot of user clients.

How can I ensure that temporary table is always deleted at the end if some kind of error occurrs?

Comment: Local temp tables are automatically dropped when they go out of scope so you can remove the `DROP` entirely.

Comment: dropping tables at the very beginning of the procedure could have side effects when the calling process has created a #temptable before executing the procedure.

Comment: @DanGuzman I also suppose that they are also deleted even if some kind of error occurs during sp execution, right?

Comment: Correct, A temporary table only persists for the duration of the scope it was created in. This can easily be tested with a few simple tests. [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=62f5b209d171beef8e1ba2e004222cc6)

Comment: Side note, SQL Server 2008 has been unsupported for over a year, you should really be looking at upgrade paths by now.

Comment: Yes, SQL Server will get rid of local tables when the proc completes, error or not. The drop may be deferred, such as in the case of an outer transaction that is not committed or rolled back, but each local temp table creation will have a unique name that will not conflict with previously created tables in the inner scopes of the same session.